# Router with access to multiple networks

Tags: router, internet, intranet

A router creates a private network and if a router has connection with the internet anyone in that private network is able to access, thru the router, the internet. The same goes for a intranet, where rather than having access to the internet, the router has access to the intranet and so does anyone within the private network created by the router. Is it possible to have a router with access to both the internet and an intranet? So that any user connected to the private network of the router can ask for access to the internet and/or the intranet? Being able to not only use the internet but also to have access to the documents and data in the intranet.

I have been asked about this and I honestly have no idea. I can see the use of that and I will probably try to do it if it is possible.

I also would want to know how it would work if it is possible.

Sorry if I have any mistake above, whether linguistic or technical. I don't have much experience working with networks.

Comment: A router which connects to internet and can be connected to by more than one device is already an intranet which has access to internet.

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321 the goal was to be able, when connecting to the router, to have access to both the internet and another network from which the router also had access, but not the user directly

Comment: You mean like [This?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BflYN.png)

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321 I have to say that I don't have much knowledge when it comes to networks. I am totally out of my comfort zone. I have a friend that is willing to help me with this project, but we have an agreement in which we only request each other's help once we are totally positive it is possible to do. I have to say that I am not sure if what you have there is what I need. I will send some schematics about it.

Comment: What the picture is displaying, is a router connected to two network switches, which have their own network. If you are talking about a router connecting to another router with separate networks that connect together, then **No**.

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321 [This](https://imgur.com/a/fB7mb) is what I need. Sorry for the quality.

Comment: Networking is a bit of a "rabbit hole", lots of options, devices, and layering.   Managed switches and/or VLANs could be helpful to reduce hardware count or just buy more switches and routers, entry level enterprise gear to share internet across networks and have more networking options.  Based on your picture what you want is possible, and there are probably MANY ways to implement it depending on the hardware you purchase/own and network topology.  This lends the question to being a hardware/software recommendation which is off topic.

Comment: **Yes.** It should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Any network directly attached to the router will have an entry in the routing table by default. Any network that is not directly attached will need a static route.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_table

You need to do your research before you jump in to network administration. Asking questions like this, it will take you a long time to learn.